# Java Stack Comparison

Tags: java, stack

I'm wondering how to accomplish this:

1. Compare two Stack objects
2. Do this recursively
3. After the method that
   does this is complete, the Stacks remain as they were to begin with
   (i.e. same order, same items).

Only the `push`, `pop` and `isEmpty` methods for `Stack` is available.

I'm looking more for theoretical help than coding help, but any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudo-code, you could do something like this:

```
boolean compareStacks(a, b) {
  if (a.isEmpty() != b.isEmpty()) return false; // check if one is empty
  if (a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) return true; // check if both are empty
  element_a = a.pop(); // grab elements and compare them
  element_b = b.pop();
  if (((element_a==null) && (element_b!=null)) || !element_a.equals(element_b)) {
    a.push(element_a); // if they are not equal, restore them and return false
    b.push(element_b);
    return false;
  }
  result = compareStacks(a, b); // compare shortened stacks recursively
  a.push(element_a); // restore elements
  b.push(element_b);
  return result; // return result from recursive call
}
```

Comment: @user: See my improvement - using try/finally you avoid the duplicate code that restores the stack states.

Answer (score 6):

Two stacks are identical if their top level elements are identical, and the remaining stacks are identical (namely, the recursive condition).

Now, think what to do just before returning from the method call, in order to leave the stacks the same way they where given at the invocation time.

---EDIT---

The working Java code (derived from **Markus A.** solution, but with an interesting use of "finally" and with generics):

```
static <T> boolean compareStacks(Stack<T> a, Stack<T> b) {
    if (a.isEmpty() != b.isEmpty()) return false; 
    if (a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty()) return true; 
    T element_a = a.pop(); 
    T element_b = b.pop();
    try {
        if (((element_a==null) && (element_b!=null)) || (!element_a.equals(element_b)))
            return false;
        return compareStacks(a, b); 
    } finally { // restore elements
        a.push(element_a); 
        b.push(element_b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that entering into the method, you would have to pop off the top element of each stack to compare... so say they're equal... then you'd have to call the method again... and pop off the next two... etc... but then you're left with two empty stacks once you've gone through all of the elements...

Comment: where / how would you push the elements so that they go back in the same order???

Comment: Push them on another stack.

Comment: No need to use another stack... that's the beauty of this question.

Comment: @EyalSchneider how would you accomplish this without using 2 auxiliary stacks?

Comment: True, any ordered collection will do. But why introduce a new data structure, when a stack is perfectly fine?

Comment: Use the "wishful thinking" principle of recursive solutions: assuming that your nested call returns the stacks in their previous state, then all you have to do is push back the item you removed before the recursive call.

Comment: but if you push it back before the recursive call... does this not just send the same stack through... comparing the same two elements?

Comment: @Eyal i know you're onto it here... i'm just having a touch of trouble understanding exactly how the method would go

Comment: So you are pushing elements onto the call stack instead of on an explicit auxiliary stack. This surely is an option.

Comment: something like......pop top two
compare
if equal, push them back...
recursive call?

Comment: @user: No, you want the recursive call to have the stacks with the top level items removed. Change the order slightly...

Comment: @eyal ok... if it's pop top two, compare if equal, recursive call, push them back.... then how would this restore the original stack? you'd be adding the elements back after a recursive call.... ughhhh

Comment: It's a nice question that shows the close relation between a stack and a recursion.

Comment: @user: Yes, exactly. It accomplishes what you want. Consider one invocation. Assuming the recursive call in it terminated leaving the stacks the way you passed them, then only the 2 top elements are missing.

Comment: 3 2 1 => pop 1 => call (stack 3 2) => pop 2 => call (stack 3) => pop 3 => empty - no call => push 3 => push 2 => push 1 (reverse order)

Comment: @user: Maybe it will be easier for you if you simulated a run on two stacks of a single element each.

Comment: @user: yes, it seems to be correct. I believe it can be a little shorter. I'll post my proposed solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

With recursion it always helps to think of it as 2 parts, a "Setup" and a recursive function.  Your setup would create the proper situation (create the two stacks, pass them in, etc) and then calls the recursive method and when the recursive method is done, report the results.

In your case you probably want this signature for the "recursive" method:

```
public boolean compareStacks(Stack one, Stack two)
```

If that method pops & compares the top tow elements of the stack, it can return false right then (saying they don't compare).  If they do, you now have two stacks, each one shorter than before.  You already know how to compare those two stacks, right (You just wrote the method to do so!).

at the end  you can "Push" your one element back onto each stack to restore it's previous state before returning.

There will be a little trickiness in restoring the stack in the case where they don't compare, and ensuring that if the compareStack you call fails it properly passes that up to the previous state, even if the "current" compareStack succeeds, but those are implementation details--just thought I'd mention those so you don't overlook them.

There is a cute solution with Try/finally (no catch, return from within the try and push back onto the stack in the finally) that would make the code pretty slick, but it's easy enough without it.